# Why is the new Java Logger failing to work consistently here?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Note how most of the other calls `Logger` calls work, and all the `System.out.println()` works, but please someone explain to me why the `Logger.info()` calls in `stop()` and in `destroy()` never print with the rest of the log, since those functions are clearly running!?  With java12, even the `destroy()` isn't showing.  Is this a bug, am I using it weird, or what?

```java
package test;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getCanonicalName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main()");
        LOGGER.info("main()");
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {
        LOGGER.info("Test()");
        System.out.println("Test()");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownThread());
    }

    public void shutdown() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("shutdown()");
        System.out.println("shutdown()");
        stop();
        destroy();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("stop()");
        System.out.println("stop()");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("destroy()");
        System.out.println("destroy()");
    }

    class ShutdownThread extends Thread {
        ShutdownThread() {
            super("app-shutdown-hook");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                shutdown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Bye! ‍♂️");
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT with both java 10 and java 11 (OpenJDK):

```
main()
Mar 14, 2020 1:53:59 PM test.Test main
INFO: main()
Mar 14, 2020 1:53:59 PM test.Test <init>
INFO: Test()
Test()
Mar 14, 2020 1:53:59 PM test.Test shutdown
INFO: shutdown()
shutdown()
stop()
destroy()
Bye! ‍♂️
```

OUTPUT with java 12 (OpenJDK):

```
main()
Mar 14, 2020 2:17:13 PM test.Test main
INFO: main()
Mar 14, 2020 2:17:13 PM test.Test <init>
INFO: Test()
Test()
shutdown()
stop()
destroy()
Bye! ‍♂️
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825403/java-how-to-get-logger-to-work-in-shutdown-hook) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is coverted in: [JDK-8161253 - LogManager$Cleaner() can prevent logging in other shutdown hooks](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161253).

Per the ticket:

> As a workaround to creating a custom shutdown hook you can create a custom handler and install it on the root logger.
>   The first action of the LogManager$Cleaner is to close all the installed handlers on the logger.
>   Once the cleaner calls the close on the custom handler you can then do one of the following:

1. Have cleaner run your shutdown code inside the handler.
2. Find your custom shutdown hook using the Thread API and join with it.

Here is solution #1:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getCanonicalName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main()");
        LOGGER.info("main()");
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {
        LOGGER.info("Test()");
        System.out.println("Test()");
        addShutdownHandler();
    }

    private void addShutdownHandler() {
        Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = root.getHandlers();

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            if (h.getClass() == ShutdownHandler.class) {
                return;
            }
        }

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            root.removeHandler(h);
        }

        root.addHandler(new ShutdownHandler());

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            root.addHandler(h);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("shutdown()");
        System.out.println("shutdown()");
        stop();
        destroy();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("stop()");
        System.out.println("stop()");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("destroy()");
        System.out.println("destroy()");
    }

    class ShutdownHandler extends Handler {
        ShutdownHandler() {
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            final String old = t.getName();
            t.setName("app-shutdown-hook");
            try {
                shutdown();
                System.out.println("Bye! ‍♂️");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                t.setName(old);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord r) {
            isLoggable(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution #2 gets tricky as we can't ensure that from a shutdown hook that another shutdown hook was started.  This means extra coding if you want to use Thread::join.  So to workaround this issue we simply use the Future API:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getCanonicalName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main()");
        LOGGER.info("main()");
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {
        LOGGER.info("Test()");
        System.out.println("Test()");
        addShutdownHandler();
    }

    private void addShutdownHandler() {
        Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = root.getHandlers();

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            if (h.getClass() == CleanerJoin.class) {
                return;
            }
        }

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            root.removeHandler(h);
        }

        root.addHandler(new CleanerJoin());

        for(Handler h : handlers) {
            root.addHandler(h);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("shutdown()");
        System.out.println("shutdown()");
        stop();
        destroy();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("stop()");
        System.out.println("stop()");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("destroy()");
        System.out.println("destroy()");
    }

    class ShutdownTask implements Callable<Void> {
        ShutdownTask() {
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            shutdown();
            System.out.println("Bye! ‍♂️");
            return null;
        }
    }

    class CleanerJoin extends Handler {
        private final FutureTask<Void> sdt = new FutureTask<>(new ShutdownTask());

        CleanerJoin() {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(sdt, "app-shutdown-hook"));
        }


        @Override
        public void close() {
            boolean interrupted = false;
            try {
                for(;;) {
                    try { //Could use LogManager to lookup timeout values and use a timed join.
                        sdt.get();
                        break;
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        reportError("Shutdown hook failed.", e, ErrorManager.CLOSE_FAILURE);
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
                        interrupted = true;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (interrupted) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord r) {
            isLoggable(r);
        }
    }
}
```